# How to position jQuery slideshow inside png

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, slideshow

I am trying to put a simple jQuery slideshow inside of a png mockup of a phone for a simple website for our app. I am using bootstrap and have a jumbotron split into two columns. I would like the left side to have the mockup phone with fading screenshots and the right side to have a logo and description. I am using [this](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/simplest-jquery-slideshow) slideshow.

[Here is the js fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6893/)

Here is what I have for html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="row">

      <!-- Slideshow Left -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="fadein">
          <img src="img/screenshot1.jpg">
          <img src="img/screenshot2.jpg">
          <img src="img/screenshot3.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="phone">
          <img src="img/phone.png">
        </div> 
      </div>

      <!-- Description Right -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>√oots</h1>
        <p>This is some shit about the game.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Slideshow plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
      4000);
});
</script>
</body>
```

and here is the css

```
.jumbotron { 
    height: 600px; 
}

.container { 
    padding-top: 65px; 
}

.fadein { 
    position:relative; 
    width:500px; 
    height:332px; 
}

.fadein img { 
    position:absolute; 
    left:0; 
    top:0;
}
```

I have searched and searched and all I can tell is that something needs to be done about absolute vs. relative with the css. I also wanted this site to utilize Bootstrap's responsive features, but I can see that I will need to do something special to make that slideshow do that. Maybe everything I used was ridiculous and you know a better way to do this?

Comment: next time, make a js fiddle for this ;)

Comment: Sorry, first post. I added it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a clean solution that will be easier to handle in case you decide to change your layout in the future. This is easier because you will just have to move the container of the phone, which will move the screen contents inside it as well, without having to re-position everything else. I mainly just made your phone class a container for the slide show, and made the phone mockup the BG of the phone class instead of using an `img` tag. Then I added a negative `z-index` value to get the screen content fitting nicely into the phone.

(You may want to consider getting the images the same size as the mockup's screen, therefore not cutting anything).

http://jsfiddle.net/h82ukey4/

```
**CSS**

    @import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
 .jumbotron {
    height: 600px;
}
.container {
    padding-top: 65px;
}
.fadein {
    position:relative;
    width:311px;
    height:480px;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: -1; /* Important. */
}
.fadein img {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.phone {
    width: 311px;
    height: 573px;
    background-image: url('http://www.smoothsand.com/gradeply/images/mockup%20galaxy%20nexus.png'); /* Important. */
}
```

This should work, check the fiddle.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This works in js fiddle; however, when I try to use the code exactly as it is locally it will not run in chrome. Any ideas what I am missing in my html document? F12 doesn't bring up any errors.

Comment: I actually found out the issue. If I get rid of the z-index, everything shows up perfect in chrome. Which is interesting since you said that's important.

Comment: @MintMentos That is strange. Well if it works then go with it. Sorry if it confused you, not sure why that happened.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the offset of your slideshow ( `.fadein` ) to be the same as your picture ( `.phone` ), then adjust accordingly to fit it onto the screen:

```
$('.fadein').offset({ 
    top: $('.phone').offset().top + 28,
    left: $('.phone').offset().left + 21 
});
```

Here is the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/6896/)**.